# Set own file-icons for selected files on JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, icons, jfilechooser, filelist

I have the following problem. I have a selected filelist and i add the files with help of the `JFileChooser`. Now i want to remove this filelist and would like to show a green tick on the selected files in `JFileChooser` instead.

Is it Possible to change the icons of some specific files in `JFileChooser` (in this case for the selected files)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it by passing a custom FileView to the [setFileView()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileView%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileView%29) method. There is even an example of doing that in the [JFileChooser tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#fileview).